# Multiple gallery thumnbnails on one page

Tags: images, gallery

I want to post multiple galleries on a single static page.

So far, I've only been able to create a gallery that puts every single picture on that one page. What I want to achieve is several images on one page (thumbnails maybe) that represent different galleries, not the same one.

How can I do that?

Comment: NextGen gallery should be able to do what you want:  http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: Do you want galleries in full? Or you want something that represents and links to gallery, if so where would galelry itself be?